# Import flask not working despite installing flask

Tags: python, flask, pip, chatbot

I get the error:
"import Flask could not be resolved"

when I have this code:

```
from Flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")
```

I've already typed "pip install flask" in the terminal - not sure what is wrong exactly?

Comment: There might be multiple python environments installed on your system. If you're using virtual environment, you first need to activate virtual environment on your terminal and then install packages.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
```

Python is case sensitive.